# How do I make a shift register from flip-flops using only two inputs?

Tags: serial, flipflop, shift-register

For a project I'm working on, I need to make a serial-in shift register out of only 74LS175N quad flip-flops, and two buttons (button for input 1 and button for input 0). I also can't use microcontrollers such as an Arduino, or premade shift register ICs, but I have access to additional ICs such as 555 timers, logic gates, and op-amps, if that helps.

I'm not really sure where to start. I've tried a few things with limited success, such as connecting the input to a double NOT gate before running it to the clock for a rudimentary time delay, but the issue I always run into is that not having a separate button for clocking inputs makes everything very finnicky and unreliable; for example, one press of the 1 input button can cause it to input multiple times; the same goes for the 0 input button.

Is there any way to smooth this out so that one button push reliably results in one input?

Comment: Please clarify: "two buttons (button for input 1 and button for input 0)". Is this a school assignment? Please share also more details about your progress (schematic is much better than the text in the second paragraph).

Comment: use the circuit tool to draw your attempt and edit the question

Comment: You are experiencing switch bounce.  You need something with a Schmitt trigger inputs,  like a 74ALS06 (just an example off the top of my head).

Answer (score 1):

> but the issue I always run into is that not having a seperate button for clocking inputs makes everything very finnicky and unreliable - for example one press of the 1 input button can cause it to input multiple times, or same thing with the 0 input button.

You need to use an edge-detector circuit to generate your clock signal. *[Working With Monostable Multivibrators](http://www.n5dux.com/ham/files/pdf/Working%20With%20Monostable%20Multivibrators.pdf)* is my favorite article on the subject.

An edge-detector converts a rising (or falling) edge into a short pulse. When used with a switch you can create a short pulse when the switch is depressed. In order to create a new pulse you would need to release the switch and press it again.

The basic idea is to create waveforms like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJXlFf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Essentially CLK is "A OR B" although there are some timing considerations to work out.

If you take "A" as the data input to your shift register it becomes the "1" button.

Note that the edge-detector also conveniently debounces your inputs.